# Jsonkey in Api Response has $

Tags: java, android, json, api, retrofit2

I'm basically using retrofit to create a request to a server, however the date is stored in mongodb and the request returns a response that contiants $date, is there a way to retrieve it?

Comment: post your response and code

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from the question title that you mean there's a json key with a dollar sign and I'll assume you're using Gson too, because that's common with Retrofit. If so, then you're looking for [SerializedName](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)

This annotation lets you specify the name in the json for the key. So in your case you'd want to add it to your model. Something like:

```
public class Foo {
  @SerializedName("$date")
  private String date;
}
```

in kotlin:

```
data class foo(
   @SerializedName("\$date")
   val date: String)
```

This annotation is used by Gson to serialize and deserialize the object into and from json.

I'm sure other libraries that can be plugged into retrofit have something similar.

Also note that on Android this annotation is very handy, because of the obfuscation tools. Usually the models are obfuscated and the variable names change. If you want to keep the right names then this is an approach to it.